# after payment fail the order cancel automatically magento2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment-gateway

when I canceled the order or payment fail the order has been canceled automatically, but actually when the payment fails the order status has not changed to canceled in magento2.

Comment: Which Payment method you are using?

Comment: I am using **Payumoney Payment**  gateway

Answer (score 0):

dose any one know how to change this code 
so it dosnt cancel order but retrieves the cart

```
else
    {

        $this->_createVivaPaymentsComment($message);
                $this->_order->cancel()->save();
        $this->_messageManager->addError("<strong>Error: </strong>" .__('Your transaction failed or has been cancelled! Please Try an alternative payment card.'). "<br/>");
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply but this ay help. not so sure about it but for me it is working.

```
$this->_cancelPayment();
            $this->_checkoutSession->restoreQuote();
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect(
                $this->getPaytmHelper()->getUrl('checkout')
            );
```